# Triggers on sqlite android does not work

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, triggers

The goal of the trigger is to insert a new record in the table column GIORNI_SETT date when I update or insert a value greater than 1 in Table SHIFTS column shift, but I can not run the trigger, obviously something wrong but I do not know what , from the log I have no errors, but the trigger does not work, someone can help me, thank you.

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
static String DATABASE_NAME="turniDB.db";
public static final String TURNI="turni";
public static final String TURNI_ID="idturno";
public static final String TURNO="turno";

public static final String GIORNI_SETT="giorni";
public static final String GIORNI_ID="giorni_id";
public static final String GIORNI="giorni";
public static final String DATA="data";

public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TURNI+" ("+TURNI_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+TURNO+" TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    String CREATE_TABLE2="CREATE TABLE "+GIORNI_SETT+" ("+GIORNI_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+GIORNI+" TEXT,"+DATA+" INTEGER)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE2);
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS AGGIUNGI_DATA AFTER UPDATE ON TURNI FOR EACH ROW WHEN (new.turno > 0) ");
    db.execSQL(" BEGIN ");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO GIORNI_SETT (data) VALUES (1);");
    db.execSQL("END;");

    db.execSQL("DROP TRIGGER AGGIUNGI_DATA;");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TURNI);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+GIORNI_SETT);
    onCreate(db);
}

public static void beginTransaction() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public static long insert(String string, Object object, ContentValues values) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: your table name is wrong. should be `... AFTER UPDATE ON turni`, or `ON " + TURNI + " ...`

Comment: also, you are creating your trigger before dropping it. It cannon work this way.

Comment: Also, your sql query (the create trigger) should be on one query, not 4, I think

Comment: Can you please review this code for me, I'm really not practical, are days that I try to trigger this function, but with no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your create trigger query should be in `onCreate` after the creation of the 2 tables, and should look like:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS AGGIUNGI_DATA AFTER UPDATE ON " 
    + TURNI + " FOR EACH ROW WHEN (new.turno > 0) BEGIN INSERT INTO "
    + GIORNI_SETT + " (data) VALUES (1); END");
```

Comment: Ok, now it seems that it works, I do not know how to thank you. Thank you thank you so much for your valuable help.